# ios facebook user info

Tags: ios, facebook

Can you help me how can I get user info.

```
  NSString *name;
[FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            // Success! Include your code to handle the results here
           name = [result objectForKey:@"first_name"]; // Error!!! how to get data from this handler
        }
        else
        {
            // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
            // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
        }

    }];
```

Code described above - asynchronous? How to make it synchronous? Tell me about the mechanism or tell me where to read. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you totally mess up. Try this code, but be sure, your understand it:

```
- (void) SetUserData
{
    [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            self.first_name  = [result objectForKey:@"first_name"];
            NSLog(@"First name just came from server: first_name: %@", self.first_name); 
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }];
    [self furtherProcessMethod];
}


- (void) furtherProcessMethod
{
    if (self.first_name == nil)
    {
        // this is not recursion, do not miss that!!
        [self performSelector:@selector(furtherProcessMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0]; 
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"First name that I can work with first_name: %@", self.first_name); 
// here you can handle you first_name, after it came
    }
}
```

So after some time you need to get in log:
First name just came from server: first_name: some name
First name that I can work with first_name: some name

Comment: I tried something like this before. futherProcessMethod will run first, than I will see NSLog of SetUserData block.

Comment: sure, it runs before, but you have this check self.first_name == nil, and than start this method again, until get result. So it is okay. Just wait until your get First name that I can work with first_name: message.

Comment: I replace this [self performSelector:@selector(furtherProcessMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0]; with [self furtherProcessMethod]; - infinite circle

Comment: This is bad idea, you need to make some delay, but not recursion - in your case it is recursion. Just copy and paste that code, that I provide and wait for result (do not change it)

Answer (score 1):

You could read everything about **Facebook SDK** on this site: https://developers.facebook.com.

They don't provide synchronous API and I don't even know why you might need it. But if you really do you can do some workaround. See implementation:

```
__block id result = nil;
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

[FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id theResult, NSError *error) {
    result = theResult;
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);    // UPDATE: dispatch_semaphore_wait call was here, which is wrong
}];

dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
NSLog(@"%@", result);// this code will be launched after you've received response from Facebook
```

**Result** conforms **FBGraphUser** protocol. So if you it doesn't contain value for **first_name** key, user wouldn't have specified it. You could print **result** in debugger and see what it is.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your response. The program goes into an infinite wait. I need it Executes when I call her and returns the data.

Comment: I've made a typo, let me fix.

Comment: Check the code now. If you never see it got to "NSLog" line, set a breakpoint inside completion handler and check if it's fired. If not, maybe, the problem is connected to your Facebook integration code.

Comment: I get data from facebook. I can see this data only inside the block. Result of your code - an infinite wait.

Comment: Did you apply my recent fix? So if you put a breakpoint to "NSLog" line, is it never fired?

Comment: This code should be executed after clicking on a button. When I click on this button the program goes into an infinite loop. 
Yes, I checked the new code.

Comment: Please, put breakpoint to completion handler. And tell me if it fires.

Comment: __block NSString *name;
    //dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id theResult, NSError *error) {
       
        name = [theResult objectForKey:@"first_name"];
        NSLog(@"1: %@", name);
       //dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];
   // dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    NSLog(@"2: %@", name);
}

Comment: Result
2014-06-25 23:03:35.430 ....[47446:60b] 2: (null)
2014-06-25 23:03:36.052 ....[47446:60b] 1: Vasily

Comment: If use dispatch_semaphore_create - infinite wait and no result (even in block)

Comment: Ok, so this approach doesn't work in this case. Hard to say why. What exact behaviour do you want to achieve so you sync fetching?

Comment: I executed the program. At one moment I need data from faсebook. This is a one-time request for data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use additional method to solve your problem:
1) make name as property: __block NSString *name
2) move you code, that you need to perform, to separate method, like that:

```
- (void) methodWithComplitionHandler
{
name = nil;
[FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
{
        if (!error)
        {
           name = [result objectForKey:@"first_name"]; 
        }
        else
        {
        }
}];
[self futherProcessMethod];
}

- (void) furtherProcessMethod
{
if (self.name == nil)
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(furtherProcessMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0]; // here set appropriate delay
    }
    else
    {
      // do some with name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! No result. Look at my current class (I post it like an answer).

Answer (score 0):

As I clarify in previous answer, you need to work with name inside "else" statement. Please, debug for more understanding. So we have:

```
- (void) SetUserData
{
    [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            self.first_name  = [result objectForKey:@"first_name"];
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }];
    [self furtherProcessMethod];

}


- (void) furtherProcessMethod
{
    if (self.first_name == nil)
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(furtherProcessMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:30.0]; // here set appropriate delay
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"first_name: %@", self.first_name); 
    }
}
```

Comment: No return data. self.first_name every time == nil.

Comment: so did you move NSLog(@"first_name: %@", self.first_name);  inside "else"? Would you provide fresh code?

Comment: hm, but what do you mean by "No return data". Do you use return statement somewhere?

Comment: I mean "else" no run.

Comment: you add big delay - 30 seconds, did you wait that time? What debug says? Are you sure, that you receive response without errors, and self.first_name get value. My suggestion - make delay smaller - 10 seconds for example, and set breakpoints here:
    {
        NSLog(@"first_name: %@", self.first_name); 
    }
and here:
if (!error)
        {
            self.first_name  = [result objectForKey:@"first_name"];
        }

Comment: When you debug code, it takes a bit more time, then normal program running. Seems like you receive response from server not very fast. That's why you need to wait a bit, until request came. Put breakpoint only in "else" statement and wait a bit (make your delay smaller - lets say 3).

Comment: Problem not in breakpoints, remove them and just wait until you get result. To be sure, that you get result, add some NSLog here: 
if (!error)
        {
            self.first_name  = [result objectForKey:@"first_name"];
            NSLog(@"Result came");
        }
and after you receive this message in log, look if you get message with first_name result after it. Do not forget make smaller delay, because if you make big delay, you need to wait a lot before you reach else statement.

Comment: I tasted this code yesterday. Inside this block I always get data.

Comment: I see, but normally request need some time for response, and you had delay 30 seconds - it is to much. Im pretty sure you did not wait that time. Please, add NSLog as you can see in comment above, and delay = 2, and just look at log and wait.

Comment: I put 1, 10, 300 sec. No result. I suppose, I should  move delay to other place. I put it (delay - simple circle) before block, after and inside. Anyway, block run after function

Comment: please look at my last answer